# Git responds with "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/Dev' by 2 commits" after merging a pull request through Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm noticing an issue where every time I accept a pull request in bitbucket and merge the feature branch into the dev branch, then come back into to my command line and do a `git pull` from within my dev branch, git responds with:

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/Dev' by 2 commits.
>
> (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

I've tried doing a `git pull`, `git pull origin`, `git pull origin Dev`, `git fetch`, `git fetch origin`, etc.

How can I resolve this?

**Edit:**

If I `git push` to clear the state, it pushes a commit with a message of:

> Merge branch 'Dev' of https://bitbucket.org/foo/bar into Dev

The pull request merge that I performed through bitbucket has a commit message of:

> Merged in feature-branch-name (pull request #3) Some changelist commit message here

And they are both time stamped with the same time. Even though I may `git push` 15 minutes later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two commits (which have local file changes that you committed previously with git commit or git merge) in your dev branch that have not been pushed to origin/Dev.

The best way to resolve it typically is to 'use "git push" which copies your local commits to the remote repository so others can pull them.

If you want to

- get rid of the two commits (and all their changes)
- get rid local working tree file changes
- return to the exact state of origin/Dev

Use this command (make sure you are in you dev branch before starting)

```
git reset --hard origin/Dev
```

At the end of this command your dev/branch and origin/Dev and the tracked local files will all match.

Answer (score 1):

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/Dev' by 2 commits.

That means you need to push, not pull or fetch.

> Merge branch 'Dev' of https://bitbucket.org/foo/bar into Dev
>   Merged in feature-branch-name (pull request #3) Some changelist commit message here

Those commits were created locally, when you accepted the pull-request. Their timestamp represents the date of their creation (ie when you accepted the PR).
You can push 15 minutes later or 15 days later, that date (of creation) will not change.